# Integrated Windows Authentication with Apache on Windows

Tags: php, windows-authentication, xampp

I'm using XAMPP and I want to use my app on my intranet, because of this I don't want to create another login page and I want to use the authentication from windows and to work with the username logged in. How can I make this work in XAMPP